# Puxar Url da variavel em window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Estou criando uma aplicação em Electron onde eu tenho um campo que a pessoa insere uma `url` e quando ela clica no botão de `submit` é direcionada para aquela `url`.

O meu html está assim:

```
<body>
    <form id="formulario">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="Insert your URL" id="campo">
            <input onclick=Start() type="submit" value="Start">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Ao clicar ele puxa uma função no documento `config.js`:

```
function Start() {    
    var InsertUrl = document.getElementById('campo').value;
    console.log(InsertUrl)
    window.location.href = + InsertUrl 
}
```

O valor da `url` está sendo impresso no `console.log`, só que não consigo puxar a `url` pra dentro do `window.location.href`.

Comment: `window.location.href = ` **`+`** `InsertUrl` esse + tá sobrando aí

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
var my_func = function(event) {
        var InsertUrl = document.getElementById('campo').value;
        console.log(InsertUrl)
        window.location.href = InsertUrl;
        event.preventDefault();
    };      

    var form = document.getElementById("formulario");
    form.addEventListener("submit", my_func, true);
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Insert your URL"   id="campo">
            <input  type="submit" value="Start">
        </div>
</form>
```

Tente assim e veja se funciona, de uma pesquisa sobre o preventDefault()

Comment: Ele não consegue ler o addEventlistener

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at config.js:9 Mas obrigado pela dica, vou pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score -2):

Fiz o procedimento acima, mesmo assim não puxava a nova página.

Após isso vi que várias pessoas tiveram o mesmo problema.

O que acontece é que o javascript carregava antes do DOM da página. Única alteração que fiz foi no HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./config.js" async></script>
```

Adicionei o async para carregar o script depois e funcionou perfeitamente.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!